# json deserialization returns null

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I pass JSON object with ajax formdata to Controller. I try to deserialize it to object, but it always returns null. I only can convert it to dynamic, but then cannot convert dynamic to Category class.

```
public class CategoryVM
{
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public CategoryImage categoryImage { get; set; }

    public CategoryVM()
    {
        category = new Category(); 
        categoryImage = new CategoryImage(); 
    }
}
```

Category class

```
public class Category
{
    public string Kategori { get; set; }
    public string Kodu { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }
}
```

JSON value:

```
{
    "cat": {
        "Category": {
            "Kategori": "xxx",
            "Kodu": "yyy",
            "State": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCat(string cat)
{
     dynamic json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cat);
     CategoryVM c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryVM >(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)); //converts null here
     return View();
}
```

I also tried JsonConvert, but not working for me:

```
CategoryVM c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryVM>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
```

Comment: That is because your json doesn't match your object. Your json clearly specifies that you have an object with a property `cat`, and inside this property is another object with your `Category` property, and inside this property you have an object with the 3 properties you added to your category class. Basically, you're missing a few levels of objects around it. Try deserializing it into `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Category>>`, and if that gives you something, look at the `"cat"` key and its dictionary, and the `Category` key and its value of that dictionary.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I wanted to shorten the code to write here. I updated my question. I already tried CategoryVM class but result is the same.

Comment: Try `Dictionary<string, CategoryVM>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra level of nesting `{"cat": { /* CategoryVM contents */ }}` that is not reflected in your data model.  The easiest way to account for this is to deserialize to a wrapper object with a `public CategoryVM cat` property, which could be an [anonymous type object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm):

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(cat, new { cat = default(CategoryVM) })
    .cat.category;
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xC7ozh).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, then you would not need `CategoryVM`:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(obj.First.First["Category"].ToString());
```